# Trying to convert characters to upper case using ASCII values (can't use toUpperCase())

Tags: java

Every time I try to convert a character using ASCII values, I get '?' as the result.  I assume it is a casting issue, but I have been trying to fix it for quite some time now with no success.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    String x = arr[j];
    char firstChar = x.charAt(0);
    firstChar += (char)32;
```

No matter what character I operate on, I get '?' as the result.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Check the encoding of your console output....

Comment: What does the string contain in the first place? The posted code doesn't produce any output. Post a complete minimal example.

Comment: Google "ascii table".  Study it.  Find out what you need to do to a character value to convert from lower case to upper case.

Comment: If you want to use an algorithm that works only for ASCII then you should first check that the character is in the ASCII range (otherwise known as the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)).) `charAt` returns the Unicode/UTF-16 code unit value. Fortunately for you, they are the same as ASCII values for characters in the C0 Controls and Basic Latin Unicode block.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
firstChar += (char)32;
```

by

```
firstChar -= 32;
```

Uppercase letters come **before** lowercase letters.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to convert lower case to upper case, you would *subtract* 32, not add it.  And you should first test that the character is in the range of lower case letters, which is 97-122, inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

UpperCase to LowerCase:

```
public static char toUpperCase(char c){
    int charASCIICode = (int) c;
    if (charASCIICode >= 97 && charASCIICode <= 122)
        return (char) (charASCIICode - 32);

    return c;
}
```